# passing an array inside a one input text

Tags: php, ajax

I have this part of code in my form. It's a dynamic input text.

jquery:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<label for=\'keywords\' style=\'display: inline; margin-left: 40px;\'><input type=\'text\' name=\'keywords[]\'></label> <a href=\'#\' onclick=\'removeElement("'+ divIdName +'")\'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Remove</a>';
```

Now, i need to pass it through ajax with this code.
ajax:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var username = $("#user_name").val();
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&username=' + username;
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "join.php",
   data: dataString,
   success: function(){
     alert('hello world');
}});
```

However, i don't know how to pass `keywords[]` using dataString variable. Can someone know how to pass it to join.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all form fields are part of a form, you can use:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "join.php",
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  success: function(){
  alert('hello world');
}});
```

That would send all form values though, not just the `name`, `username` and `keywords` fields

Comment: thanks! I spent 2hours in passing dataString and you gave me one line of code! :D great!